Apollo Angular - Update local data after mutation
I am tryign to update the local data after a mutation execution.
This mutation removes a item from a list, so i want to remove that item from the local data list.
Unfortunately I always end up with this warning.

Cache data may be lost when replacing the cars field of a Query
object.

Here is my code:
export const KeyCarFields = gql`
fragment KeyCarFields on Car {
  id
  make
  model
  year
}`;

const getCarsByDealershipIdQuery = gql`
${KeyCarFields}
query GetCarsByDealershipId($id: UUID!) {
  cars(where: { dealership: { some: { id: { eq: $id } } } }) {
    ...KeyCarFields
  },
}`;

getCarsByDealershipId = (id: string) => this.apollo.watchQuery({
  query: getCarsByDealershipIdQuery,
  variables: {
    id: id
  }
}).valueChanges.pipe(map((result: any) => result.data.cars));

removeCarFromDealership = (input: { dealershipId: string, carId: string }) => this.apollo.mutate<any>({
  mutation: gql`
  mutation RemoveCarFromDealership($input: RemoveCarFromDealership!) {
    removeCarFromDealership(input: $input) {
      boolean
    }
  }`,
  variables: {
    input: input
  },
  update: (store, { data: { removeCarFromDealership } }) => {
    if (removeCarFromDealership.boolean) {
      const data: any = store.readQuery({
        query: getCarsByDealershipIdQuery,
        variables: { id: input.dealershipId }
      });

      const updatedCarsList = data.cars.filter((car: any) => car.id !== input.carId);

      store.writeQuery({
        query: getCarsByDealershipIdQuery,
        variables: { id: input.dealershipId },
        data: {
          cars: updatedCarsList
        }
      });
    }
  }
}).pipe(map((result: any) => result.data.removeCarFromDealership.boolean));

This will work, but again risk of clearing cache is high.
What am i missing here?
